# Task.Wait() - Is the waiting thread for the task suspended

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

All;

Consider this line of code:

```
task.Wait();
```

I understand that the calling thread will be blocked from executing the code below this line until the task is finished.

My question is:
Is the blocked thread effectively placed in a suspended state? In other words, it is not going to be scheduled on the CPU, hence it will not consume any CPU resources until the task completes?

So far I found this quote:

"Wait could simply block on some synchronization primitive"
from
"https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-wait-and-inlining/"

It appears that the my understanding is correct based on the above statement. After all, that's what I understand "block on sync primitive" means.

Anyone can confirm this?

Thanks.

Comment: Technically, it depends on the task scheduler implementation (you can have custom ones) but very few of those would implement a busy waiting strategy, so yes, it's probably fair to say the thread won't consume CPU resources until the wait is released. Note that bookkeeping for waiting threads and context switching can still incur some overhead in terms of CPU cycles, even if it's not as much as a continuously running thread would be, so saying that it won't consume *any* CPU resources is probably going too far.

Comment: your also completely ignoring memory usage. Blocked threads still consume memory. You should always try and avoid blocking async threads.

Comment: @Liam The question was about CPU, I know it consumes memory and I know it is expensive. ...

Comment: @JeroenMostert Makes sense. I was more concerned that the implementation doesn't run a polling while() loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,2991

It doing `SpinThenBlockingWait` to reduce context switching and also inlines `Task` continuations, if not created with `RunContinuationsAsynchronously`. So it does a little busy wait, but usually no more than any other synchroniztion primitive (like `lock (obj) {}`).

Comment: Thanks for the linking to the actual method call. Interesting.

Comment: @ActiveX see also NetFX implementation https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,3259
 But as always: do not code against implementations, code against interfaces.

Comment: "do not code against implementations, code against interfaces. " - Obviously yes. This was more of curiosity thing as I am very thorough.